# Elasticsearch - script_fields error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic 1.5.0. When I run this block in the query:

```
"script_fields" : {
        "test1" : {
            "script" : "doc['actual_air_time'].value * 2",
             "lang":"groovy"
        }
    }
```

I get an error:

```
nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]
```

How can I enable groovy script for elastic? Is there any other way to evaluate "test1" without using script_fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable it in elasticsearch.yml, by setting:

```
script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true
```

For more details see: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Comment: oops, I checked the link before but missed the section on enabling it. Thanks.